# Time Parsing in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
{"creator"=>{"siteStandardProfileRequest"=>{"url"=>"http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=966636&authToken=TVqk&authType=name&trk=api*a188142*s196271*"}, "lastName"=>"Emge", "id"=>"EZDn5fpc6X", "pictureUrl"=>"http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_gxkFOrh6iNKSaMhhxOX4OPnLizvm2VTh0ZKZOPFJpPTY1Yn8AMNIK1PcD4zl7j82yyQJAqJM7R4U", "firstName"=>"Ryan O."}, "creationTimestamp"=>1355124057000, "text"=>"Being that it positions itself as a the backbone of the internet, it appears that there will be many long term opportunities in this space.", "id"=>"g-66325-S-194331620-108220061"}
```

But the `creationTimestamp` has this format `1355124057000`. I want to change it to `Sat Dec 15 04:13:14 +0000 2012`. I am using ruby on rails, ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.4
How can I change this?

Comment: Please ensure your datatype of that field is `datetime` or else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the `Time.at` function

```
t = Time.at(1355124057) # for seconds since epoch
t = Time.at(1355124057000/1000) # for milliseconds since epoch
```

This is the time in seconds [since epoch](http://www.epochconverter.com/) (Jan 1st, 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

Once you get the time object `t` apply [`strftime`](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/strftime/) to convert the time to string in whichver manner you like

So in your case, it would be

```
t.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%m:%S %z %Y")
```

Comment: t = Time.at(1355124057000)
  RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'
 from (irb):6:in `at'
 from (irb):6   I got this type of error

Comment: I think you have too many zeros a the end.
It should be 1355124057 and not more. Check it out

Comment: If it does have 000 at the end, its probably miliseconds since epoch ?
So you can always do a 1355124057000/1000 to convert to seconds since epoch